# Gridview created duplicate rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview that populate with an item from the listview is click.
However my Gridview will create duplicate rows upon trigger from list view item command.

My listview and gridview are on the same page.

Any solution to avoid that?

The following code is how i bind data to gridview from listview item_command method:

```
protected void loadDataEvent(string categoryid)
{
    Module_Category mc = new Module_Category();

    gvEventByCategory.DataSource = mc.Get_All_Event_By_Category(categoryid);
    gvEventByCategory.DataBind();
}

protected void lkbtnCatItem_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Enter")
    {
        loadDataEvent(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post method for binding `Gridview`?

Comment: You're unlikely to get an answer with so little information. Can you at least better describe what is happening, what you want to happen and what you have tried already? Some code wouldn't hurt either...

Comment: hint: autogenerateColumn ="false" in gridview

Comment: Hi asif Ahmad, I have tried that too

Comment: You need to show the code of `Get_All_Event_By_Category` as well

Comment: may be problem with your query.try fetching **distinct** values

Comment: @shreesha hi, thanks for your advice. manage to spot my mistakes. =)